# Error on Serialize Child Object

Tags: python

ERROR:"Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `parent` on serializer `WarningSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `warning` instance.
Original exception text was: 'warning' object has no attribute 'parent'."

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = player
        fields=('name','family','state')

class WarningSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent=PlayerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = warning
        fields=('parent','minute')
```